# Copying Based on a Criteria and Pasting to Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get my code to copy based on a criteria (there are multiple cells fitting the criteria) and then paste it to another sheet below the cells that're already there.  I've been using .AutoFilter to do this.

I wrote the below code but it errors out at .AutoFilter and at ws1.copyFrom.Copy.

Background:
The criteria is "Active" found in Sheets("Future Project Hopper") which is located in Column D15 and below. 
Copy data from D:J columns that match above criteria.
Paste it to Sheets("CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active") in range C25:J25 below the data that's already there.

Is there a way to do this?

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Future Project Hopper")
Set ws2 = wb1.Worksheets("CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active")

Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Macro?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

If Answer = vbYes Then

With ws1

    'clearing any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

       lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

            With .Range("D1:D" & lRow)

                'filtering on column D
                .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Active"
                'Defining range that should be copied - Need C through J and it copies until it's blank cells
                Set copyFrom = .Range("C15:J15" & .Rows.Count).End(xlDown)

            End With

    'clearing any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With

    'copy range and paste into other worksheet
    ws1.copyFrom.Copy
    ws2.Range("C25:J25").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=False


End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Instead of autofiltering, loop through the list, and if the row meets the criteria, move the cell. Also, power query can accomplish this with very little effort

Comment: Your filter method is fine - you just need to copy the `SpecialCells` of type `Visible`

Comment: Yes, it will always start on row 25 for CPD sheet and Row 15 for Future Project Hopper.  I have other information above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Copy Criteria Range

```vb
Sub CopyCriteriaRange()

    Const cCrit As Variant = "D"      ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cCols As String = "C:J"     ' Source/Target Data Columns
    Const cFRsrc As Long = 15         ' Source First Row

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet              ' Source Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet              ' Target Workbook
    Dim rng As Range                  ' Filter Range, Copy Range
    Dim lRow As Long                  ' Last Row Number
    Dim FRtgt As Long                 ' Target First Row
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult      ' Message Box

    ' Create references to worksheets.
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Future Project Hopper")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active")
    End With

    Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Macro?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

    If Answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ws1
        ' Clear any filters.
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        ' Calculate Last Row.
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCrit).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Calculate Filter Column Range.
        Set rng = .Cells(cFRsrc, cCrit).Resize(lRow - cFRsrc + 1)
        ' Make an offset for the filter to start a row before (above) and
        ' end a row after (below).
        With rng.Offset(-1).Resize(lRow - cFRsrc + 3)
            ' Filter data in Criteria Column.
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Active"
        End With
        ' Create a reference to the Copy Range.
        Set rng = .Columns(cCols).Resize(rng.Rows.Count).Offset(cFRsrc - 1) _
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' Clear remaining filters.
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    ' Calculate Target First Row.
    FRtgt = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, cCrit).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ' Copy Copy Range and paste to Target Worksheet.
    rng.Copy
    ws2.Columns(cCols).Resize(1).Offset(FRtgt - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008! Only issue is it copies Active projects and pastes the values onto old project in the CPD sheet.  Do I need to change part of the code to be `end.(xlup)`?

Comment: sorry I realized I wasn't very clear.  The projects start on row 25 and continue down the column.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @ApogWay: Fixed it.

Comment: That worked! If I wanted to delete the "Active" from the "Future Project Hopper" would that just be a `Sheets("Future Projects Hopper").Activate` `rng.delete`?

Comment: @ApogWay: It would delete the data. Usually ClearContents is used to preserve the formatting or Clear to not. But you can always try it, not save the workbook and reopen the workbook. But if you want to delete the rows, you would use **rng.Rows.Delete**: Bye,bye Active. Be careful, it cannot be undone. And be careful when using filters. You were using field 4 in column D range, which was referring to column H. It's the 4th field only in a range from column A.

Comment: The `rng.Rows.ClearContents` works perfect!  Thanks for clarifying everything.

Comment: Last question but if I wanted to filter the data on "Future Project Hopper" to be in A to Z is there a filter that can do that? Reason I ask is so I don't have empty cleared cells in the middle of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code; i replaced the .autofilter with .showalldata for clearing filters on the sheet. The error handling that envelops .showalldata is in case there are no filters on the sheet to begin with. I also added '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)' to the range that you're trying to copy so that it attempts to copy only the visible cells that results from the filtering.
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

```
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Future Project Hopper")
Set ws2 = wb1.Worksheets("CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active")

Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Macro?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

If Answer = vbYes Then

With ws1

'clearing any filters
On Error Resume Next
.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

   lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        With .Range("D1:D" & lRow)

            'filtering on column D
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Active"
            'Defining range that should be copied - Need C through J and it copies             until it's blank cells
            Set copyFrom = .Range("C15:J15" & .Rows.Count).End(xlDown).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        End With

'clearing any filters
.AutoFilterMode = False

End With

'copy range and paste into other worksheet
ws1.copyFrom.Copy
ws2.Range("C25").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,     Transpose:=False


End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thank you @MahmoudMostafa! I'm hitting another error with this section: `ws1.copyFrom.Copy ws2.Range("C25:J25").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=False` I'm assuming I'm not referencing the correct destination but can't figure which part.

Comment: I edited the code. You should paste to a single cell "C25", and the data will be laid out starting from that cell.